# Create Admin LoginPage With Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, authentication, crud

I'm trying to create some admin login. I think my code is correct because when I input wrong email and password the error message appears on login page. However, when I input correct data of my DB, it also shows error message.

Please help me. I appreciate any answer.

my controller (Admin.php):

```
public function index()
{
    $this->admindashboard();
}
public function admindashboard()
{
    $data = array();
    /* $data['main_content'] = $this->load->view('admin_main', '', TRUE); */
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_main', $data);
}
public function admin_regst()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['main_content'] = $this->load->view('admin-regist', '', TRUE);
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_main', $data);
}
```

My other controller (Login_admin.php):

```
 public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}
public function adminchecklogin()
{
    $data = array();
    $adminemail = $this->input->post('admin_email', TRUE);
    $adminpassword = $this->input->post('admin_psw', TRUE);
    $this->load->model('M_login_admin');
    $admindetails = $this->M_login_admin->admin_login_check($adminemail);
    if (password_verify($adminpassword, $admindetails->admin_psw)) {
        if ($admindetails->admin_status == 1) {
            $session_data['adminid'] = $admindetails->admin_id;
            $session_data['adminemail'] = $admindetails->admin_email;
            $session_data['adminusername'] = $admindetails->admin_username;
            $session_data['adminstatus'] = $admindetails->admin_status;
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
            redirect('Admin');
        } else {
            $data['error_msg'] = "User ini tidak aktif....!!!";

            redirect('login', $data);
        }
    } else {

        redirect('error-login', $data);
    }
}
public function login_error()
{
    $data['error_msg'] = "Email atau Password Anda Salah....!!!";
    $this->load->view('login', $data);
}
```

my model (M_login_admin.php):

```
public function admin_login_check($adminemail)
{
    $admin_details = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('admin')
        ->where('admin_email', $adminemail)
        ->get()
        ->row();
    return $admin_details;
}
```

my view(login.php):

```
<body>
<section class="hero is-fullheight">
    <div class="hero-body container has-text-centered">
        <div class="login">
            <img src="https://logoipsum.com/logo/logo-1.svg" width="325px" />
            <p>
                <?php
                if (isset($success_msg)) {
                    echo $success_msg;
                }
                ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php
                if (isset($error_msg)) {
                    echo $error_msg;
                }
                ?>
            </p>
            <form action="<?= base_url(); ?>Login_admin/adminchecklogin" method="POST">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <input class="input is-medium is-rounded" type="email" placeholder="hello@example.com" autocomplete="username" name="admin_email" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <input class="input is-medium is-rounded" type="password" placeholder="**********" autocomplete="current-password" name="admin_psw" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field has-text-left ml-3 mt-5">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="button is-block is-fullwidth is-primary is-medium is-rounded" type="submit">
                    Login
                </button>
            </form>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[My route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKxNV.png)

[DB Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRelN.png)

[DB Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKMvI.png)

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djSHN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your database has the `admin_psw` in plain text that would explain why the `password_verify()` is failing.

In order to use password_verify(), you have to have hashed the password using `password_hash()` This would normally be done when the user first registers or any time the user changes their password

> Check the documentation for `password_hash()` [in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm trying to change admin password on my DB using hash for "admin" then when i try input on my login page using hash or plain text it's still show error message.

Comment: Do it properly. Fix the registrations form, or create a MakeAdmin form. Run the password_hash as part of creating the user, then the password_verify will work

Comment: Hi i was try add the registration with this modal ` $data['admin_psw'] = password_hash($this->input->post('admin_psw', true), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`. The registration is success but, when i try it on login page admin it's still show error_message.